# getting the error when using sed in a loop- sed:no input files

Tags: sed, ksh

I am using `sed` within a while loop to remove the trailing blank spaces from a file containing a list of files. The blank spaces are being removed. But I'm getting the message `sed:no input files`.

Following is the while loop I am using:

```
while IFS= read -r line; 
        do
            echo "tester: $line"
            sed -i 's/\s*$//' $line ;
        done < file_list.txt
```

Comment: Blank line at the end of `file_list.txt`?

Comment: Yes. the piece of code is working. But I am getting messages of 'sed:no input files'

Comment: No, what do you see if you do `tail -1 file_list.txt`? If you don't see anything except an empty line then you need to delete that empty line.

Comment: I see output of a blank line

Comment: Let me explain deeper. I have a file file_list.txt which contains a list of filenames to be processed. And for all the files present in the file_list.txt I have to remove the trailing blank spaces and extra newline characters. I am using while loop to read the file names and process using sed command.

Comment: When `$line` is empty, your sed command becomes `sed -i 's/\s*$//' ;` -- with no file. You must quote the variable: `sed -i 's/\s*$//' "$line"`

Comment: When I quote the variable , the error says 'no such file or directory'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ipor and glenn have both said, based on your report from B Layer's comment regarding `tail -1 file_list.txt`, since there is a blank line at the end of that file, when the `while` loop reads that blank line, the `$line` variable gets assigned an empty value, leaving no filename for `sed` to process.

```
$ cat i
file1
file2

$ while IFS= read -r line; do printf -- "-->%s<--\n" "$line"; done < i
-->file1<--
-->file2<--
--><--
```

The fix here is to delete that trailing blank line from file_list.txt, or wrap a test around your actual processing to test for the existence of the file:

```
# do ...
if [ -f "$line" ]
then
  # process file
fi
# done ...
```

---

and [always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/117549)!

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, for me it was because I did not pass the input file to sed CMD

Example:

```
boy=$1
boy2=$2
boy3=$3
while IFS="," read -r col1 col2
do
 if [ "$col1" == "oke" ]; then

    sed -i "s/$col2/$boy/g" test.txt
  fi
done < test.txt
```